# simple jquery, animate on load not working

Tags: jquery, css, onload

I have some images I would like to animate to 100% opacity once the page has loaded.

I have this code but for some reason it does not work.

Css code is...

```
#photos img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}​
```

Jquery code is...

```
$(function(){
    $('#photos img').on("load", function(){
        $(this).addClass("loaded");
    });
});​
```

I have the jsfiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/rzdzf/

I'm sure I am missing something really small...? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read **Caveats of the load event when used with images** at http://api.jquery.com/load-event/?

Comment: very interesting, I will allow this technique then, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure you properly read the caveats of the load event. The point is that you cannot rely on image `load` events if you want every visit to your webpage to functional properly.

Comment: Jasper what I meant was there is no point me using it if it is not functioning consistently, but it seems $(window).load seems to work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like this...

```
$('#photos img').animate({opacity: 1}, 1500 );
```

**Or for on load:**

```
$('#photos img').on("load", function(){
     $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: Th works perfectly, thank you, however how do you feel about this, a good point raised by j08691 - Caveats of the load event when used with images at api.jquery.com/load-event?

Comment: @Adam Because of browser caching, it's tricky to bind to image `load` events because who knows if the image is already loaded (in which case your `load` event handler won't fire).

Comment: That is also a good way to do it. I tried to match to what you were doing but my first thought was to used $(window).load(function(){});

Comment: Yes Kris this seems to work more consistently. Spot on Jasper

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I like this answer but it is not using CSS3 for the animation which would be cool but I guess if something is already loaded/cached... like Jasper mentioned, the load event won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just in this fiddle, it's because the setting on the left pane says to run the code onLoad; but then you have an onLoad in there, but it's already loaded so it doesn't run. Change it to nowrap. When I did this it worked as expected.

Comment: No reason to down-vote this, it's actually true, the OPs JSFiddle was improperly setup. See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/rzdzf/ (the setting is in the top left of the view-port).

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your script :

```
$(function(){
    $('#photos img').animate({opacity:1});
    });​
```

Comment: Could you explain your approach?

Comment: @noc2spam  this works but it won't bind the animate function to the img when it loads.

Comment: @Jasper It is supposed to animate the opacity from .2 to 1 on page load. I used the fiddle posted by the OP and my solution worked in the fiddle. What i see is that your answer is the best in this context (because you have specifically bound the function on to the window load. For a real life project this would be the answer). Everyone should upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just bind to the `window.load` event, all images will be loaded at that point. This is helpful because of issues with binding to image `load` events. Because of browser caching, who knows if the image is already loaded (in which case your load event handler won't fire)

```
//run this in the global scope, the `window` object is always available
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $('#photos img').addClass("loaded");
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rzdzf/10/

Also your `.loaded` class is not being applied because it is less specific than the `#photos img` rule, so just make it more specific:

```
#photos img.loaded {
    opacity : 1;
}
```